# Solving Particle in Box problem using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, textbook-and-exercises

I am new to quantum computing,  I would like to ask how can I solve simple particle in box problem using qiskit which allows to compute the bound states in finite quantum well.
[Finite quantum well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well)